# Declare global variables and use in many functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have done a fair bit of searching and keep failing. I'm looking to declare a set of variables that are taken as user input and use these in a number of functions. The only way I have got this to work is to include all the variables in each function, so the script ends up large and repetitive. Can I declare the variables to be used in one place and access them in many functions? Below is
a stripped down version with one function in it. Cheers

```js
var df = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
var rh = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt3").value);
var u = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt4").value);

function ffdicalc(df, t, rh, u) {
  var ffdi = 2 * Math.exp(-0.45 + 0.987 * Math.log(df) + 0.0338 * t - 0.03458 * rh + 0.0234 * u).toFixed(3);
  document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = ffdi;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta Charset="UTF-8">
   <title>FBT</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <header>
   </header>
   <main>
    <form>
      Enter Drought Factor (1 - 10) : <input type="number" id="txt1", min="0" max="10"><br>
      Enter Temperature in Degrees Celcius : <input type="number" id="txt2", min="-20" max="60"><br>
      Enter Relative Humidity : <input type="number" id="txt3", min="0" max="100"><br>
      Enter Wind Speed in Km/s : <input type="number" id="txt4", min="0" max="100"><br>
      <button type = "button" onclick="ffdicalc()">Calculate</button>
    </form>
      <p>
        <table class="center">
          <tr>
          <th><a href="#" title="The FFDI is calculated by...">FFDI</a></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td id="result1"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </p>
   </main>
      <div class="wrapper">
       <footer>
       </footer>
      </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SagarV, `var` has nothing to do with global. only the place of declareing makes them global, if declared outside of any function.

Comment: Thank you, I understand both of these comments. But the function doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The variables *are* global. The problem is what you putting in them.

You are copying the values of the inputs to the variables. You are doing this when the script loads, at which time they have only their default values.

You **aren't** creating a reference to the values of the inputs.

If the user enters a value into any of the inputs then the variables are **not** updated.

---

You could store the inputs in the variables (`var foo = document.getElementById('foo')`) and then read the current values when you need them (`do_something_with(foo.value)`)

Comment: thank you very much. This has worked for me. Much appreciated.